# Consul: Cannot connect service to Consul server hosted in Docker container

Tags: docker, consul

I am trying to connect to a Consul server hosted in a Docker container.

I used the below command to launch the Consul server on docker,

```
docker run -d -p 8500:8500 -p 8600:8600/udp --name=CS1 consul agent -server -ui -node=server-1 -bootstrap-expect=1 -client=0.0.0.0 -bind=0.0.0.0
```

The Consul sever is successfully launched and I can access the UI on my host machine using the URL http://localhost:8500/ui/dc1/nodes.

Below is the log for the Consul server as shown by Docker,

```
==> Starting Consul agent...

Version: '1.9.2'

Node ID: 'cc205268-1f9d-3cf6-2104-f09cbd01dd9d'

Node name: 'server-1'

Datacenter: 'dc1' (Segment: '<all>')

Server: true (Bootstrap: true)

Client Addr: [0.0.0.0] (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, gRPC: -1, DNS: 8600)

Cluster Addr: 172.17.0.2 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)

Encrypt: Gossip: false, TLS-Outgoing: false, TLS-Incoming: false, Auto-Encrypt-TLS: false
```

Now I have a .Net core 3.1 web api service which I am trying to register with the Consul server. **The service is running on the host machine.**
I'm using IP address 172.17.0.2 and Port 8500.

However I'm unable to register the service and I get an error message as below,

```
The requested address is not valid in its context.
```

I would appreciate if anyone can suggest if I'm doing anything wrong or how to register a service running on host machine with a Consul server hosted in a docker container?

Comment: Can you also share the service definition you are using?

Comment: @BlakeCovarrubias: My service is actually an API Gateway which is using Ocelot. https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/servicediscovery.html. My definition in the service config file is "ServiceDiscoveryProvider": {
    "Scheme": "http",
    "Host": "172.17.0.2",
    "Port": 8500,
    "Type": "Consul"
}.